# How to divide one array with unknown number of values into sub-arrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array in MATLAB which the total number of elements is unknown, but it is always multiple of 32. How can I transform this array into a cell array in which each of its positions will contain 32 values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [num2cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html):

```
a = rand(1,32*5);
result = num2cell(reshape(a,[],32),2);
```